# Any way for Grunt to covert Javascript files to CoffeeScript?

Tags: gruntjs

Curious if there is anyway for Grunt to compile Javascript to CoffeeScript. Any tips? Thanks for the help, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using following grunt plugin:
https://gemnasium.com/npms/grunt-js2coffee

Sources:
https://github.com/jonschlinkert/grunt-js2coffee

Comment: Nice! However, it keeps saying the following:

Local Npm module "js2coffee" not found. Is it installed?
Warning: Task "js2coffee" not found. Use --force to continue.

I've gone ahead and installed via npm install js2coffee --save-dev and the package.json seems to have the file in there... so not sure what's going on...

Comment: Have you loaded it in using grunt? `grunt.loadNpmTask("grunt-js2coffee");`in your Gruntfile.

Comment: Yes, I've tried loading it in via yours, as well as the one in the documentation:

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-js2coffee');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('js2coffee');